# Is a separate "writer" thread always needed (in a socket reader/file writer client)?

Tags: java, multithreading, writer

I have some client code that reads from a socket (via an input stream) and writes to a file (via a BufferedWriter) in a loop:

```
dataInStream = new BufferedInputStream(dataSocket.getInputStream());
outputFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
byte bytes[] = new byte[64];
Message msg = new Message();
int bytesRead = 0;
while (true) {                
   bytesRead = dataInStream.read(bytes, 0, 64);
   // create a message from the raw data...
   msg.parse(bytes);
   // write it to the file as a String
   outputFile.write(msg.toString());
   outputFile.flush();
}
```

**(simplified code to show general flow - I'm only interested in learning when I need to add an extra writer thread)**

At what point (data rate-wise) might I need to split out the file write operation into another thread (i.e., the "writer") with something like a **ConcurrentLinkedQueue** between the reader and writer threads?

My requirement message rates are low (i.e. 1400 byte msgs at max ~10 per sec)

Test code I ran to benchmark throughput showed it could easily handle 150000 bytes/second.
Since the data rate (whatever it turns out to be) is constant, can the writer ever block long enough to cause data loss at the reader?

Or is it just good practice to *always* have a reader *and* a writer thread?

Answer (score 0):

> At what point (data rate-wise) might I need to split out the file write operation into another thread (i.e., the "writer")

You should *only* start optimizing your code (making it more complicated) when you are having performance problems or a profiler tells you it is a good idea.

> Or is it just good practice to always have a reader and a writer thread?

It is good practice with no other information.  But in your case you know the data requirements so you should only do it if you expect a large amount of throughput or if you expect to be IO bound on the disk side.

> My requirement message rates are low (i.e. 1400 byte msgs at max ~10 per sec)

This is just not a lot of data throughput to warrant the extra code complexity

> can the writer ever block long enough to cause data loss at the reader?

In most situations, local disk IO is going to be faster than network.  It is possible to run into this situation but I would think it is not very common.  The kernel is giving you a lot of buffering on the socket and the TCP/IP protocol will retransmit if you overflow kernel buffers so that even if you *do* block for a large amount of time, you won't lose data.

Comment: thanks for the lightning fast response! You've confirmed my suspicions. (a little paranoia never hurts...)